# Blackbody curve in RGB for objects less than 1500 K?

Tags: star, temperature, black-body

We know the colors of stars that have a temperature greater than 1000-1500 K, shown [here.](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html) However, I am wondering about those stars/brown dwarfs with surface temperatures of less than 1500 K. Is there a blackbody curve for these temperatures, and are there any set RGB values for them?

Comment: Color is hard.  Did you look at https://github.com/anisotropela/Universe-timeline/blob/master/timeline.py (by Pela of this parish)   This is close to a duplicate of your previous quesion https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/what-is-the-rgb-curve-for-blackbodies

Comment: Such objects are nowhere near blackbodies.

Answer (score -1):

So I use the following logic:

1. Define 'red', 'green' and 'blue' light in terms of the wavelength ranges those colours encompass (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum#Spectral_colors))
2. Calculate the average [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law) across each wavelength range, for a defined temperature
3. Define the RGB value to be the relative ratios of each colour's spectral radiance with 255 defined as the colour with the largest spectral radiance

***I made a Python script which you can find [here](https://gofile.io/d/8djhHo) to calculate, display and show the appearance of the corresponding RGB value***. Within the script, just change the value of the `stellar_temperature` variable to see the RGB values of stars of different temperatures.

The script is then finished off with a simple plot to show the appearance of that RGB value.

Now there are a couple of assumptions of course:

1. RGB values can be defined in terms of radiance/luminosity/flux ratios at each wavelength... This obviously breaks down if you have a detector which gets saturated at certain flux levels! I presume the human eye might fit that description.
2. Stars can be modelled by perfect blackbody spectra. I believe this to be a pretty valid assumption when the accuracy level needed is differentiation of different RGB tones...
3. No foreground extinction/absorption by atmosphere/dust etc.

Comment: Okay, so when I ran the program, temperatures below 1000 K appeared bright red (255,0,0) no matter what. This seems like a bug; normally, it would fade to black. Can you update your program to correct this issue?
Also, the colors seem inaccurate compared to actual values, shown [here](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html).

Comment: So I believe the ratios of the intensities are handled differently in the reference you sent on. While in the script I initially uploaded, the intensity (and therefore R:G:B) ratios are handled linearly, the reference you sent handles them logarithmically. I will upload a revised version (still ironing some things out) of the script to let you choose. However, the reference also mentions 'gamut' correction which I am unfamiliar with as a non-colour-techie person! The logarithmic-ratio based colours are certainly much closer to those of the reference you sent on anyways...

Comment: Brown dwarfs are *nothing* like blackbodies.

Comment: How would you describe their spectra? If you include any absorption lines (of which I'm sure there's plenty), you aren't approximating any more, imo.

Comment: There are approximations and things which are completely wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a reference with the spectral profile of brown dwarves in general?

Comment: You can just search for "brown dwarf spectrum" or "T dwarf spectrum" to see many examples.